# jQuery .each doesn't iterate over all descendants

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, each

I've tried a few ways of doing it, but just can't get it done.

I'm designing menu on ul/li's. I want to make it so if a `<li>` has href attribute, jQuery creates an event for it to redirect to the site which the attribute storages. But when there is no href, nothing happens.
The problem is while I click some li, the ones in the same branch are also getting the event

```
$("#menu-h > li li").each(function() {

      if($(this).attr("href")) {
           $(this).click(function() {
                window.location = $(this).attr("href");
                return false;
           });
      }
});
```

It seems that `each()` doesn't iterate over all 'li's after `#menu-h > li`, but only on direct descendants (children), so when I'll click more inside li, like `#menu-h > li > li`, the $(this) value storages the DOM element of it's parent. Is it the problem of wrong selector, or I just can't iterate over all descendants, only the direct ones?

Comment: Try `$("#menu-h li[href]")`

Comment: Please include a sample of the HTML

Comment: Events propagate. If you click on an element, you click on its parents as well. If you want to stop propagation, you need to do so explicitly

Comment: How can I get it done? I've tried using event.stopPropagation() inside if, outside if, but it works as before or stops the event completely (doesn't redirect even after clicking the right li)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate through each element and add the click event handler, you can find all `li`s with `href` attribute using the selector `li[href]`.

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu-h li[href]").click(function() {
        if($(this).attr("href")) {
            window.location = $(this).attr("href");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

A better solution will be to use event delegation

```
$("#menu-h").on('click', 'li[href]', function() {
    if($(this).attr("href")) {
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: That helped a lot, but didn't solve it :/ But I've found the problem: I use next menu "ul" inside previous "li", so jQuery runs the event if I click some other li inside - technically, it's still previous li area. Is there a way to stop it? I use position: absolute, so the ul's are practically outside the parent li.